# Bootstrap 3 radio input to change language by URL

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that manages languages by pages:

- mysite.com/en/page1 <---- this is the english version
- mysite.com/es/page1 <---- this is the spanish version
- mysite.com/fr/page1 <---- this is the french version

At the moment I use links in a navigation to open the pages in different languages. I would like to change this navigation to a modal.

Therefore I use the standard bootstrap 3 modal with radio inputs for the languages:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-lang" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select language</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">English</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Francais</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Espanol</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would you make the "Save" button point to the URL that represents the current page in the chosen language and how would you get/store those values?

As we need to use jquery for this I guess I can no longer set the path via PHP so I would need a function that will

- read the current page URL
- replace the parent-language-page (/$language/$currentPage)
- based on the checked radio button.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide a working example based on the code above? I´m very new to jquery so this would really help me. Also I´m missing values for the radio inputs, right?

Comment: Use can get current url using window.location.href and replace language part of url and then reload that url.

Comment: Let me make a sample for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(function() {

  $(".btn-change-lang").click(function() {
    var language = $("input[name=optradio]:checked").val();
    var url = window.location.href;

    url = url.replace(/^http?:\/\//, '').split('/');
    url[1] = language;
    var newUrl = url.join("/");
    newUrl = "http://" + newUrl;
    console.log(newUrl);
    window.location.href = newUrl;
  });
  $('#modal-lang').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var url = url.replace(/^http?:\/\//, '').split('/');
    language = url[1];
    $("input[value=" + language + "]").prop("checked", "checked");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="4" data-target="#modal-lang" href="#">Select Language</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-lang" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select language</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" value="en" name="optradio" checked>English</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" value="fr" name="optradio">Francais</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" value="es" name="optradio">Espanol</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-change-lang">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but at the moment it always points to /en/ regardless of input. When you run the snippet and open the console you will see that it always throws the 404 on /en/undefined. Same happens on my machine. It also adds the full path resulting in something like mysite.com/mysite.com/en/ when fired from the top-level-page

Comment: Should be mysite.com/en/ when fired from the frontpage and mysite.com/en/page1 when fired from for example mysite.com/es/page1 when en is selected

Comment: It will work fine if your url is in the format mysite.com/en/page1. You need to pay with url to fullfill your need

Comment: will test again

Comment: Check my updated answer now it will only replace second segment of your url and copy other url as its is . Now it will work for mysite.com/en/page1 as well as mysite.com/en

Comment: One more thing that i forgot to add (:checked) in selector. Now it work fine

Comment: Yes, the selector is working now. One problem could be that I am in a local environment right now so my URLs are localhost/en/... Still it seems like it adds the domain after it as you can see in this picture I took from the chrome developer console when running your snippet. [link](http://imgur.com/a/EORC3)

Comment: I set up the folders like I told in the question but it returns http://localhost/fr/localhost/en/ when I select en from http://localhost/fr/

Comment: It is because new url does not start with http:// so it append to previous one. check now

Comment: Looks good in console will test on my machine now and give feedback asap.

Comment: Works perfectly. Want bonus points for having the current language checked when opening the modal?

Comment: Use modal show event to set selected language http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events